# Identify polygon by property attribute in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, polygon, leaflet, geojson, fields-attributes

On a Leaflet map, I need to get the center using **polylabel** of a polygon which needs to be identified by **geo_id**.

[Codepen here.](http://codepen.io/rc_web/pen/vmYVpw)

A snippet of what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".button").click(function(){

    var parcelNumber = $(this).attr('name');
    var matchingPolys = sections.filter(function (feature){
              return feature.properties.geo_id === parcelNumber;
            });
            var singlePoly = matchingPolys[0];
      var pcenter = polylabel(singlePoly, 1.0);
            console.log(parcelNumber);
            console.log(pcenter);
    });
});
```

This gives me an error of **polygon is undefined** from polylabel, which means the loop isn't selecting or outputting the polygon correctly.

Answer (score 3):

This ended up being the solution. Select polygon, find center, then place marker.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".button").click(function(){

    var parcelNumber = $(this).attr('name');
    var matchingPolys = sections.filter(function (feature){
              return feature.properties.geo_id === parseInt(parcelNumber);
            });
            var singlePoly = matchingPolys[0];
      var pcenter = polylabel(singlePoly.geometry.coordinates, 1.0).reverse();

    var marker = L.marker(pcenter).addTo(map);
    });
});
```